# Print json from mysql

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi all I have a site developed in codeigniter.
In some function I have to retrieve data from mysql and print the result in javascript because is an ajax call.

Thi is my php function to retrieve data:

```
public function getCityByNameOnly($name) {
      $query = $this->db->query('SELECT *  FROM city WHERE name LIKE "%'.$name.'%" ');
      $city = array();
      foreach ($query->result() as $row)
     array_push($city, $row);
     return json_encode($city);
      }
}
```

And this is my ajax call:

```
$('#ricerca-ajax').keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val.length>2){
            var site_url_city ="<?php echo(site_url('/city/get_city_by_text')); ?>";
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city, 
                type: "POST", 
                data: {search: val},
                dataType: "text",             
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                    {
                          $('#msgid').append(data[i].name_en  + '<br> ');

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

I append the result into a div but is always undefined.
This is the console.log of my created json:

```
{"id":"125","name_it":"L&egrave;sina (Hvar)","name_en":"Hvar","nation_id":"23","region_id":"0","active":"1"},{"id":"127","name_it":"Trogir (Tra&ugrave;)","name_en":"Trogir","nation_id":"23","region_id":"0","active":"1"},{"id":"1088","name_it":"Citt&agrave; del Capo","name_en":"Cape Town","nation_id":"101","region_id":"0","active":"1"}]
```

How to print this json into my success function in javascript?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the `datatype:"json"` in the ajax will solve the issue

```
$('#ricerca-ajax').keyup(function(){
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val.length>2){
            var site_url_city ="<?php echo(site_url('/city/get_city_by_text')); ?>";
            $.ajax({   
                url: site_url_city, 
                type: "POST", 
                data: {search: val},
                dataType: "json",             
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                    {
                          $('#msgid').append(data[i].name  + '<br> ');

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })
```

Comment: yes before I was disabled to accept because the time is 15 minutes I think tahnks again